# How does Apple Pay NFC work if the NFC SDK can’t write?

Tags: ios, nfc

From what I understand, on iOS 11 the NFC SDK can’t write NFC tags. How, then, does the 2-way-communication required for NFC payment systems done???

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not expose an API to app programmers for writing NFC data. That doesn't mean that the hardware isn't capable of two-way communication.

Apple developers have access to the hardware through APIs that are not exposed generally.